# Command line FTP client WITHOUT SPEED LIMIT

Tags: performance, session, limit, ftp-client

Recently, I'm using default FTP client in Windows 7 to download files from server.
However, even I used "mget" to download multiple files but it only downloads files one by one and the speed is very slow.

Try downloading with FileZilla, I can get maximum speed when downloading 10 files at the same time.

Hence, I would like to find an FTP client which should be able to download multiple files at the same time (multiple sessions) without speed limitation.

Does anyone have suggestion for me?

Thank you all !

Comment: maybe useful: [In DOS or command line FTP, to transfer several files, you can use the commands mput (Multiple PUT) and mget (Multiple GET)](https://techjourney.net/upload-mput-and-download-mget-multiple-files-automatically-in-ftp-transfer/).

Comment: Dear Ryan,
Thanks for your suggestion but I've tried and it's only to download files one by one without Y/N prompt.
All I need is to download a number of files at the same times.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper way to solve this

1. Use ftp -s:ftpScript.txt to run automatically some FTP commands after FTP start
2. Use Windows batch file to start multiple CMD sessions, each session is used for one FTP client

Hope this help